# Is there a way to get the recipient contact category when writing an email?

Tags: vba, outlook

I have assigned contacts in my outlook to various categories. So I want to create a rule such that if I send an email to any contact in one of the category, the email is Bcc'ed to an email address.

Here's the code I currently have and I keep getting the error 438 for line `Set oContact = oRecip.GetContact`

```
Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim oContact As Outlook.ContactItem
    Dim oRecip
    Dim Recip As Recipient
    Dim BccRecip As String
    Dim strCategoryName As String



Set oRecipients = Item.Recipients
Set oRecipient = Recipients(1)

    Set oContact = oRecipient.GetContact

    strCategoryName = oContact.Categories


    strCategoryName = oContact.Categories

    If InStr(LCase(strCategoryName), "test") > 0 Then
        BccRecip = "abc@def.com"
    Else
        Exit Sub
    End If


    Set Recip = Item.Recipients.Add(BccRecip)
    Recip.Type = olBCC

    If Recip.Resolve Then
        Cancel = False
    Else
        Cancel = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Change `Set oRecipient =Recipients(1)` to `Set oRecipient =oRecipients(1)`? Please consider adding `Option Explicit` to this module too!

Answer (score 1):

oRecip in your code is a collection of recipients.

You have to use something like

```
   Set oRecipients = Item.Recipients
   Set oRecipient = Recipients(1)
```

Comment: So I edited the code as you suggested and now i get a compile error - "Sub or Function not Defined"

Comment: It was a typo in my code. The second line should be    
         Set oRecipient = oRecipients(1)